# Adding an android phon to a DNS server?

Tags: android, dns

I want to know if it is possible and how to, make an application, that allows me to put my android phone in a DNS server, as we do in a Windows PC. I want to identify my android phone by a name in a DNS network, obviously in a network in which there is a DNS server.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Probably more of a superuser.com question.

Comment: Create a reservation for the MAC address of the phone in the DHCP server and your problem is solved

Comment: What the DNS name should resolve to - LAN IP address or cellular (3G/whatever) address or what ? Where it should be accessible from - your home/office network or globally from internet ? What exactly you "do in a Windows PC" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you have three options:

1. Static IP. Sometimes it's possible to get a fixed IP for your phone, in this case you need to setup a DNS record only once, and it requires no software nor configuration on the phone itself. All you need is just create a regular DNS address record. (Consult your DNS administrator (or ask on superuser.com if your need help))
2. Home/office network (DHCP). If you want to access your phone via LAN, and this LAN have a DHCP server under your control, DHCP server can be configured to update a DNS record whenever your phone connects. In this case too, the phone does not need any special configuration/software - it's a DHCP server which needs to be configured.
3. Dynamic DNS. Your phone can submit it's address via dynamic DNS. This will work for any case - LAN (including NAT) and cellular connection. You usually need to subscribe to some dynamic DNS service for this and yes, there are dynamic DNS clients for Android. Try [net-me.net guide on setting up dynamic DNS under Android](https://www.net-me.net/client#android-neil) *(I am affiliated)*.

*(For what purpose you want access your phone, which software will listen to incoming connections, and if the phone IP will be accessible from anywhere - it's all a completely different story.)*

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS and DHCP servers support it, you can get the DHCP server to automatically update the DNS server.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787034(v=ws.10).aspx for a description of how to do it with Microsoft's servers.